# Is HTML5-mode URL routing with AngularJS possible when in local-file based apps (with file://)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router

I appligize if this has already been asked already but I can not find any information about this.

I have an AngularJS application which will be accessed from the hard drive (not from a HTTP server) so the URL in the address will be something like file:///home/user/desktop/app.html)

I am not able to get HTML5-mode URL routing to work. I am using UI-routing module for AngularJS, and whenever I go to file://..../app.html/somepage), the routing does not work. If I set HTML5 mode to false in $locationProvider, and then I go to file://.../app.html#/somepage then it does work.

So is it possible to do? Can someone show me a example where file://-hosted app can with with a URL like file:///myapp.html/somepage ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `file://` pseudo-protocol directly queries the local filesystem. For 'fancy' URLs like `/myapp.html/somepage` to work you need to have a mechanism in between, like Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) which handles those fancy URLs. Since those don't work on the file system, you're out of luck.

Install something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to test websites locally through a webserver that is capable of these things.

Comment: Niels, please clarify one thing. Is an in-between mechanism like mod_rewrite or FallbackResource (or some other url-rewriting mechanism) the ONLY way to get the pretty URLs to work with AngularJS in HTML5 mode? I thought that this is supported on a Browser level and should work if the user is using a modern browser?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location does say "requires server-side configuration" for html5 mode.

Comment: No, the browser cannot support this from simple HTTP perspective. It **has** to be done serverside.